# Copy views from one database to other database

Tags: sql-server

I want to copy views from one database to other database I had near around 70-75 views.
How can it be possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

select DB and Right Click

[image: Right Click on database]

then this window will appear click Next

[image: Click Next]

then select DB object which you want to generate script

[image: Select View and Click Next]

select file path if you want to change

[image: select file path]
then Click Next 2 times and check path which you selected and pickup that script from there and run it